# HybridRelations laravel mongo is really slow

Tags: laravel, mongodb

Used HybridRelations to store user notifications in mongoDB instead of mysql and imported 3million records and now user->notifications()->take(5)->get() or user->notifications()->paginate(5) takes over 30 seconds.
any idea how to speed it up?
on mysql with same amount of records it took 200 milliseconds.

notificaiton model has user_id and description and priority and read flag and user_id is set as an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the column that you are sorting by should be an index as well as the columns you use where clause on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this suggestion can help you.

When use `user->notifications()` means the query like that

```
db.notificaiton.find( {"user_id": <?> } )
```

That will get all record by user_id.

You can dump the `user->notifications()` and check. That should be `Collection` type and contains more than 5 records.

The solution is [this](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#mongodb-specific-operations).
You can write specific method to ensure what your mongo query expression.